# directx feature level and code

Tags: directx, directx-11

I coded a program with direct11 and my feature level coded like this

```
unsigned int featureLevel[4] =
{
    D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_11_1,
    D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_11_0,
    D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_10_1,
    D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_10_0
};
```

I am curious that why this program can work in feature level 10 even if I coded only direct11?

If I used direct11 version functions, should the program run only direct11?

Comment: I recommend you to have a look at [Direct3D feature levels](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476876%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) on MSDN.

Answer (score 0):

I think the feature levels have nothing to do with directx api version. Different feature level has different feature which is useful for game developer such as partial constant buffer updates,16bpp rendering, partial clears and so on.